# Do you need line of sight to cast spell with Divine Ward?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, line-of-sight

I suspect so, since you needed to touch the person in the first place, which, clearly, requires line of sight. But how good of a line of sight? Can you do it to someone with cover?

Even so, the feat description says that you create a bond between you and the intended target, so maybe you are casting the spell through the bond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the "Divine Ward" feat from PHBII, that lets you extend a spell from range Touch to range Short when you target the guy you're warding?  I had a cleric PC of mine take that once.

I'm not sure what you mean by "you needed to touch the person in the first place".  You mean "the spell used to be range Touch?"  I don't think that's directly relevant.

But yes, you need to be able to see them (or touch them) to target them.  "[Some spells have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself. You must be able to see or touch the target, and you must specifically choose that target. You do not have to select your target until you finish casting the spell.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm) "

I think as long as you can see them it's OK.  So in other words you need "line of sight," [which is only blocked by total cover or total concealment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatModifiers.htm).

Now, the rules do say that it takes a 1 foot square hole in a wall to make it not total cover and allow line of effect.  So I'd say in general same thing goes for line of sight to a target.  As a DM I'd allow Perception checks for edge cases like "He's wrapped up in a cloaker but trying to get a hand free so you can heal him."